# How do I get a sum of a list or array?

Tags: python, ruby

I have a list/array and I want to get the sum of all the values. I have been trying this:

```
@w12,@sv2,@sv4,@sv6,@sv8,@sv10,@sv12=75,95,110,104,101,110,116
@supers = [["5", @w12], ["6", @w12], ["7", @w12], ["8", @w12], ["16", @w12], ["17", @w12], ["18", @w12], ["9", @sv2], ["11", @sv2], ["12", @sv2], ["13", @sv2], ["14", @sv2], ["15", @sv2], ["19", @sv4], ["23", @sv4], ["24", @sv4], ["25", @sv4], ["26", @sv4], ["28", @sv6], ["29", @sv6], ["30", @sv6], ["31", @sv6], ["32", @sv6], ["33", @sv6], ["35", @sv8], ["36", @sv8], ["37", @sv8], ["38", @sv8], ["39", @sv8], ["40", @sv8], ["41", @sv8], ["42", @sv8], ["43", @sv8], ["44", @sv8], ["45", @sv8], ["46", @sv8], ["47", @sv8], ["48", @sv8], ["49", @sv8], ["50", @sv8], ["52", @sv10], ["53", @sv10], ["55", @sv10], ["57", @sv10], ["58", @sv10], ["59", @sv10], ["60", @sv10], ["61", @sv10], ["62", @sv10], ["63", @sv10], ["64", @sv10], ["65", @sv10], ["66", @sv10], ["68", @sv2], ["71", @sv12], ["72", @sv12], ["73", @sv12], ["74", @sv12], ["75", @sv12], ["76", @sv12], ["77", @sv12], ["78", @sv12], ["79", @sv12], ["80", @sv12], ["81", @sv12], ["82", @sv12], ["83", @sv12], ["84", @sv12]]
def getSum
    sum = 0
    @supers.each do |weight,number|
           sum += number
    end
    return sum
end
```

In Python I would do this:

```
def getSum():
   total sum([x[1] for x in supers])
   return total
```

How do I fix this? The total should come up to 7034.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please use the minimum sample data set necessary to demonstrate/reproduce your question. Anything beyond that clutters your question making it hard to read, and wastes our time reading around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
@supers.map(&:last).inject(:+)
```

You first get all an array of all the numbers with [`map(&:last)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) then you just add them all with [`inject(:+)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject).

Comment: @user2757899 if you care about perf, the best would be to do everything in an inject like `@supers.inject(0) { |(weight, number), e| e + number }`

Comment: I see, thank you for the help again though. I'm pretty new to ruby